# How can I remove the parentheses from equation cross-references in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, cross-reference, equation-editor, caption

It is common in mathematical articles to number displayed equations with integers in parentheses:  (1), (2), etc., and to cross-reference these equations using numbers without parentheses:  Eq. 1, Eq. 2, etc.

However, I am having difficulty implementing this in Word 2013.  I have successfully constructed a center-justified displayed equation with a right-justified equation number in parentheses by creating a 1 x 3 table, inserting the equation into the middle cell of the table, inserting the number as a caption in the right-hand cell of the table, and removing the border lines of the table.  This is the standard approach recommended online and seems to work fine.  The result is something like this:

> ```
>                                  a = b + c                               (1)
> ```

However, when I try to cross-reference this equation (Insert > Cross-reference), Word inserts

- "(1)" if I select "Entire caption",
- "(1" if I select "Only label and number", and
- ")" if I select "Only caption text".

How can I insert a cross-reference of just "1" to produce "Eq. 1"?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-remove-the-parentheses-from-equation/9abd5beb-b6ea-4a42-abb6-ac48d4ef8611. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is an extra step. You need to cross-reference to a bookmark.

You can bookmark *just the number* in the caption and assign a name to the bookmark like "Eq1." Then cross-reference to the bookmark rather than the equation. If the caption number is updated and then the cross-reference updated, they will be dynamic.

See this [temporary link for a document demonstrating using bookmarks to the numbers only](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuq61ptbxjpkgcc/CrossReference%20to%20Equation%20Bookmarks.docx?dl=0).

Comment: Ha!  This does appear to work.  Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: You are welcome.